# Using multiple tomcat instances with 80 port

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat, port

I have three tomcat instances for three different applications. They are using 8080,8081,8082 ports in one machine. How can I change configurations so that users are able to access from 80 port with different host names? I have installed an Apache on my machine and tried to configure it with following tutorial: [How to load balance Tomcat 5.5 with Apache on Windows](http://thought-bytes.blogspot.com/2007/03/how-to-load-balance-tomcat-55-with.html) until load balancing point starts. I have questions based on this tutorial. My web applications is under webapps/ROOT in all tomcat instances. 
I have this configuration in `httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule jk_module>
    JkWorkersFile  D:\containters\_tomcat_backend\conf\workers.properties
    JkShmFile      D:\containters\_tomcat_backend\logs\mod_jk.shm
    JkLogFile      D:\containters\_tomcat_backend\logs\mod_jk.log
    JkLogLevel debug
    JkMount / worker1
    JkMount / worker2
</IfModule>
```

And I'm getting this warining when I run httpd.exe from command prompt:

> [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts

Am I in correct way to make my applications work with 80 port? And how can I configure this warning?

Comment: Please have alook at these steps mentioned on this [LINK](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/webpages/configureht.html), that's how I managed to make it work :-) Now I can simply run two instances together (may be more, never tried it) [First Instance](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/) and this is the [Second Instance of TOMCAT 7.0.29](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to:8181/beerv1/)

Comment: Thank you @GagandeepBali, do I have to create a virtual host because when I start apache it says `NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts` and I don't know how to set it up. The link which you give also doesn't tell to set up a virtual host. Have you configured virtual host for your these two tomcat instances?

Comment: Actually, I just made the said changes to my **Apache HTTP Server**, and I installed Tomcat twice at two different locations, that's it and it worked. I made no other changes to any file, other then those mentioned in the link. I had declared no Virtual hosts anywhere, other then what comes with installed tomcat.

Comment: (Virtual hosts are as is, as they come with installed tomcat.) I had done no changes to them anywhere. It's best to reinstall from beginning, or else if you had the backup, bring your modified files to original state first and start over :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your scenario, you will not need load balancing. In your httpd.conf, you should define 3 virtual hosts for the host names you want to use (as described [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)). In each of the `VirtualHost` directives, insert a
`JkMount` for a worker to be defined in your workers.properties like:

```
JkMount /* worker1
...

# same for worker2 and worker3 in the other virt. hosts
```

Now comes the workers.properties:

```
...
worker.list = worker1, worker2, worker3

worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.type=ajp13

worker.worker2.port=8010
worker.worker2.host=localhost
worker.worker3.type=ajp13

worker.worker3.port=8011
worker.worker3.host=localhost
worker.worker3.type=ajp13
```

N.B.: I use different ports than the ones you specified, because communication between Apache and Tomcat is  runs via [AJP](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/ajp.html). Finally, add a matching AJP connector in each of your tomcat's server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" />
```

See [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html) for more details. The warning you mentioned seems to be caused by an incomplete virtual host configuration. Are there no `VirtualHost` instances defined yet?

**Edit**: If you don't like that much configuration, you could also use your Apache as a proxy and distribute traffic to your tomcats via the `ProxyPass`/`ProxyPassReverse` directives.